# Apache mod_rewrite Clean URLs

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using CodeIgniter on PHP and it produces the following URLs:

```
http://my.domain.com/app/index.php?/admin/main/
```

the `/index.php?` is redundant so I remove it successfully with the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

however, I would also like to remove the `/app` part, but when I do so, I get a 500 error. Is this related to Code Igniter - or how do I rewrite this rule correctly (if possible)? I tried with the following:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./app\/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: is this rewrite in the virtualhost config or a .htaccess file?

Comment: This is in an .htaccess file. Should it be moved to the main config? I have root access to the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but that is a really old way of writing the htaccess for CI if the htaccess is in the main dir of the project just use the universal htaccess code below (this does not need excluded directories and such like the old one i.e.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
```

so it is also better and like I said universal)

*It will not solve your issue with the directory but this is the best way for CI in handling the index.php removal without having to go back each time you add say a docs folder or something.

Awesome htaccess:

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding rewritebase `RewriteBase   /Path/to/directory/DirectoryBelowApps/`